# Multiplying a large integer with a digit. What's wrong my code?

Tags: c++, c++14

I am trying to solve [FCTRL2](https://www.spoj.com/problems/FCTRL2/) in SPOJ. The program should be able to calculate the factorial of numbers up to 100.

In order to solve the problem I should be able to multiply large numbers. To achieve this, I wrote the numbers as strings and applied the grade school multiplication algorithm. There is a helper function in my code called multiply1 that multiplies a large number with a digit. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string multiply1(string sx, string sy)
{
    string res(sx.size() + 1, 'x');
    int rem = 0;

    for (int i = sx.size() - 1; i >= 1; i--)
    {
     int ix = sx[i] - '0';
     res[i + 1] = ((ix*(sy[0] - '0') + rem) % 10);
     res.replace(i + 1, i + 2, to_string((ix*(sy[0] - '0') + rem) % 10));
     rem = (ix - (ix % 10)) / 10;

    }
    int ix = sx[0] - '0';
    string last = to_string(ix*(sy[0] - '0') + rem);
    if (last.size() == 1)
    {
        res[1] = last[0]; string res2; 
        for (int i = 1; i < res.size(); i++) 
        { 
            res2[i - 1] = res[i]; 
        }
        return res2; 
    }
    else 
    { 
        res[1] = last[1]; 
        res[0] = last[0]; 
        return res; 
    }
    return res;

}

int main() 
{

    cout << multiply1("155557452", "3");
    return 0;
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140D.dll
File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\xstring
Line: 2944

Expression: string subscript out of range

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
```

What does 'Debug Assertion Failed' mean and how do I fix this error?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: sorry, but doesnt "string subscript out of range" tell you already what is wrong?

Comment: Are you aware that the type unsigned long long int can handle values up to 18446744073709551615 (2power64-1)?

Comment: It's much easier to first convert the string to a vector of numbers. Also, store the least significant digit first.

Comment: @ravenspoint 100! is 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000.

Comment: when I execute your program there is no error, including under _valgrind_, it just writes an empty string at end

Comment: BTW, in Visual Studio when you get this exception break into the debugger then use the callstack tab to see exactly what line of your code caused the exception.

Comment: You are having several possible out of bounds accesses besides the one that throws this exception: E.g., in line res[i + 1] = ((ix*(sy[0] - '0') + rem) % 10);. It would be simpler for you, when building a string from scratch using the push_back operation. Then you dont need to deal with the index of the target string. Of course this slightly less efficient, but shouldnt hurt you in the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use Microsoft Visual Studio to debug programs compiled in Debug Mode, there are a lot of checks added to your code to head off Undefined or otherwise improperly set code in your program. "Debug Assertion Failed" is the generic message you get when one of these common mistakes, that the Debug Runtime Library expressly tests for, was detected.

The actual message you need to care about comes a few lines down in the error:

> ```
> Expression: string subscript out of range
> ```

Telling you that you are attempting to access outside the bounds of your strings.

My best guess is that the suspect line is this section of code:

```
if (last.size() == 1)
{
    res[1] = last[0]; string res2; 
    for (int i = 1; i < res.size(); i++) 
    { 
        res2[i - 1] = res[i]; 
    }
    return res2; 
}
```

`res2` is being declared, but it never has its size allocated or changed. Your code simply presupposes that the string has capacity and attempts to assign characters within it. That's Undefined Behavior, but because your compiler is trying to help you, it instead declares this as defined behavior that throws an exception, and the exception isn't getting caught.

It looks like `res2` is supposed to have a size equal to the size of `res` minus 1, so my advice is to simply manually resize `res2` in this code:

```
if (last.size() == 1)
{
    res[1] = last[0]; string res2; 
    res2.resize(res.size() - 1);
    for (int i = 1; i < res.size(); i++) 
    { 
        res2[i - 1] = res[i]; 
    }
    return res2; 
}
```

This should fix this specific instance of bad behavior.

I also suggest you scan the rest of your code for errors like this.

---

One other thing. It seems like you're write your own arbitrary-precision integer arithmetic. If this is part of a school assignment (or just something you're trying to teach yourself), then keep working on it, using the advice I've provided here.

If, however, this is intended for a hobby project or professional project, I advise you instead use a well-established Arbitrary-Precision Arithmetic library, instead of trying to reinvent the wheel. I recommend using [`boost.multiprecision`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html) or GMP, depending on your needs as a developer.

Comment: Thanks! But now I am just getting a wrong answer. I think I'll use vectors instead of strings as suggested above and check my logic.